# Why the string defined by Heredoc syntax inherits the properties from HTML tags above

Tags: php, html

I am new in learning PHP and even in coding overall. Please see the code below and parse it in your browser

```
<?php
echo "<h3> Below is an examples of Heredoc Syntax in PHP<h3>";
$foo = <<<XYZ
This is a string using heredoc syntax.
XYZ;
    echo $foo;
?>
```

Whey the string stored in $foo inherits the properties of h3 tag above when parsed in a browser? Should it not return plain text? Help please.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the first `<h3>` tag properly. Instead you're starting a new one. So in actuality you have *two* `h3` elements, neither with a closing tag...

If you close it correctly, it should work as expected:

```
echo "<h3> Below is an examples of Heredoc Syntax in PHP</h3>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close `<h3> </h3>` tag.. instead you opened it again